# UICollectionView iOS8 Wrong Offset

Tags: ios8, uicollectionview

Surprisingly, after updating to `iOS8` my app does not behave as in `iOS7`.
In particular, I made a calendar with `UICollectionView`. In iOS7 fine, the month cells were displayed correctly. But in `iOS8`...
[image]

I see an offset toward the top, that's the cells are shifted upward...I do not understand, really.... The code is very simple.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 UINib * nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"AgendaYearCollectionCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:agendaYearCellIdentifier];
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout  = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing      = 0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing           = 1;
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout];
}
```

The collection was not scrollable. If I make it scrollable, I can scroll and see the cells of the first row. But I do not want a scrollable collection. 
I think the problem is in the inset. In fact, if I play with:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 2, 50, 60);

 }
```

I can eventually get the first row again. But how to calculate the value for all the screen/devices? My app is landscape only and only for iPad.
What Apple changed?

Comment: I have a similar problem now. For me it looks like the *contents* of the cells are shifted down. I have a UIImageView in each cell, and the images are displayed like 20 or so points down, compared to running on iOS 7/6, or using the existing app on app store on iOS 8 devices - the difference is likely the SDK used when compiling (iOS 7 SDK vs the new iOS 8 SDK). If I have enough content to be able to scroll around in the collection view, any subsequent refreshed cells seem to appear normal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964653/incorrect-position-of-content-within-uicollectionview-in-ios-8

Answer (score 1):

Your Collection View has negative top offset. Providing more code could help, however let's try this first.

You called:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                    layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
    insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
```

I would not call this unless you want different insets for different sections. It looks like you have only one section. I would configure it with Flow Layout:

```
flowLayout.sectionInset = CGSizeMake(40.0, 2.0, 50.0, 60.0);
```

I recommend to drop iOS 7 support, all devices with iOS 7 can be upgraded to 8.

> how to calculate the value for all the screen/devices?

Should be the same offset for any iPad. Even if Apple will ship iPad with bigger screen, your offset will be the same. If you want Universal app with support for iPhone you could put device condition check and assign different numbers depending on the device paradigm.

Also, it could be something on the top. Did you messed with Navigation Bar? It doesn't clear from the picture.